# With jQuery how I assign the json array to the index of the jquery array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

Suppose I am retrieving the data(in json form) from the **first.php** and **second.php**(coding in php). I want to assign this json data in the array of the jQuery array. let the array is `var total = [index1,index2]` the first json data coming from the **first.php** will assign to the first **index** of the `total` and the second json data coming from **second.php** assign to the second index of the `total`. how will I do this. I have tried the following code. I am the bigner so if there is any mistake then sorry. for replying me thank you.

jquery

```
var total = ['index1','index2'];
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
var method = "GET";
var url = "first.php";
var asynchronous = true;

ajax.open(method,url,asynchronous);
    //sending ajax request.
ajax.send();

//receiving response from  the first.php
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(this.readyState== 4 && this.status == 200){ //readyState==4 means request is finish and response is ready 
    //status==200 is 'OK'
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for(var a=0; a<data.length; a++){
        total['index1']=data[a];
    }
  }
}console.log(total['index1']); //i want the output here

var url="second.php";
ajax.open(method,url,asynchronous);
ajax.send();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(this.readyState== 4 && this.status == 200){ //readyState==4 means request is finish and response is ready 
    //status==200 is 'OK'
    var data1 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for(var a=0; a<data1.length; a++){
        total['index2']=data1[a];
    }
  } 
}
```

first.php

```
include 'connection.php';

$data = array();
$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tabel_name ORDER BY id ASC");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $data[] =$row; 
    };
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

second.php

```
include 'connection.php';

$data = array();
$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tabel_name ORDER BY id ASC");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $data[] =$row; 
    };
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I just wan to assign the first json array to index1 and show in `console.log` and second json array to the index2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. You use "this" in onreadystatechange callback, but "this" don't design your "ajax" variable.

I have renamed your "ajax" variable in "ajax1" and I have created a second "ajax2".

Please try this code :

```
var total = {index1: [], index2: []};
var ajax1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var method = "GET";
var url = "first.php";
var asynchronous = true;

ajax1.open(method,url,asynchronous);

//receiving response from  the first.php
ajax1.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajax1.readyState== 4 && ajax1.status == 200){ //readyState==4 means request is finish and response is ready
        //status==200 is 'OK'
        var data = JSON.parse(ajax1.responseText);
        for(var a=0; a<data.length; a++){
            total['index1'].push(data[a]);
        }
        console.log('=== index1 ===');
        console.log(total['index1']); //i want the output here
    }
}
//sending ajax request.
ajax1.send();


var ajax2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url="second.php";
ajax2.open(method,url,asynchronous);
ajax2.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajax2.readyState== 4 && ajax2.status == 200){ //readyState==4 means request is finish and response is ready
        //status==200 is 'OK'
        var data1 = JSON.parse(ajax2.responseText);
        for(var a=0; a<data1.length; a++){
            total['index2'].push(data1[a]);
        }
        console.log('=== index2 ===');
        console.log(total['index2']); //i want the output here
    }
}
ajax2.send();
```

Comment: thanks for it. I have a Question in my mind? can i ask?

Comment: ` total['index1']` in this the array will be there it means the first index of the total? i m right its equal to **total['index1'] means total={index:[]}**?? I am right

Comment: total['index1'] = total.index1
You can created it by var total = {index1: []}
However total['index1'] is not total={index:[]} because "1" is missing.
Note that "index1" is your initial key and we could have another key like "myindex" : total['myindex'] = total.myindex or total={myindex:[]}

Comment: Yeahh yeah sorry i missed "1"

Answer (score 0):

You use a wrong property "lenght". A correct property is "length" in your "for" statements.

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(this.readyState== 4 && this.status == 200){ //readyState==4 means request is finish and response is ready 
    //status==200 is 'OK'
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for(var a=0; a<data.length; a++){
        total['index1']=data[a];
    }

    // Here, server has returned response
    console.log(total['index1']); //i want the output here
  }
}
// Here, server has not yet returned response
```

Comment: sorry i editted my question now you can see the right one

Comment: Ok, your console.log is run immediatly but ajax request is not already returned.

Try insert console.log(total); just after your for statement in onreadystatechange callback.

Comment: my code is right or wrong. is the json data will correctly assigning to the indexs? you can edit my question and post it. as a answer

Comment: I think he's right, but you are in asynchronous mode. So, your server answers after you have ran console.log(total['index1']).

Comment: actually i am not getting you properly can you elaborate it for me?

Comment: Are you sure that first.php and second.php returns a correct json ? Execute them directly in your browser to check results or verify result from your browser network inspector module.

Comment: yeah i am sure i test your program also. tell me first i am  assigning the correct to the indexs

Comment: You need use push() method : total['index1'].push(data[a]);